# Where do I define a queue and how do I load BFS in the code?

Tags: python, queue, breadth-first-search

I have a code for performing Breadth-First Search on a graph and I tried to invoke the BFS procedure (like: BFS(graph, "A", "C") however it is showing me an error. I need to define MyQUEUE, how and where exactly do I define it?

I tried making a class queue and defining it however it keeps showing me an error

```
def BFS(graph,start,end):
  q = MyQUEUE() # make an empty queue first
  q.enqueue([start]) # add the start node onto the queue
  while q.IsEmpty() == False:
       path = q.dequeue()
       last_node = path[len(path)-1]
       print (path)
       if last_node == end:
           print ("VALID_PATH : ", path)
       for link_node in graph[last_node]:
           if link_node not in path:
                new_path = []
                new_path = path + [link_node]
                q.enqueue(new_path)

graph = {'A': ['B', 'C','E'],
 'B': ['A','C', 'D'],
 'C': ['D'],
 'D': ['C'],
 'E': ['F','D'],
 'F': ['C']}
```

I expect to make invoking BFS in a shell (BFS(graph, node1, node2) working properly so it finds all available trails.

Comment: 'it keeps showing me an error' - well, can you show us as well? Please include the complete error traceback in your question! Also, see how to create a [mcve] - there's no way we can try and run your code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    BFS(graph, "A", "C")
  File "C:x", line 7, in BFS
    q = MyQUEUE() # make an empty queue first
NameError: global name 'MyQUEUE' is not defined

Comment: Please add the traceback **in the question itself**, rather than in comments. Anyway, the message is clear: `MyQUEUE`doesn't exist here. Where did you define it? Are you certain of the spelling?

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a queue data structure as part of its `collections` module (it's called, somewhat confusingly, [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)). As it pertains to your situation, you would use `append()` for `enqueue` and `popleft()` for `dequeue` (or `appendleft()` and `pop()`).

That said, if I were implementing a simple FIFO `MyQUEUE` class to your simple specifications, using just a simple list, it would look something like this:

```
class MyQUEUE:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []  # start with an empty list

    def enqueue(self, elem):
        self.queue.append(elem)  # add element to back of list

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.queue.pop(0)  # remove element from front of list
```

Comment: `queue` is specifically designed for inter-thread synchronization. The generic `queue` name is unfortunate. The correct choice of data structure for a queue *not* used for inter-thread communication is `collections.deque`.

Comment: Huh, TIL. That'll teach me to do quick google searches without investigating the results thoroughly.

Comment: Also, the brackets in `q.enqueue([start])` are deliberate, as the queue in this implementation stores paths, not nodes. (It doesn't look like a very good implementation - there doesn't seem to be anything to avoid repeatedly searching the same nodes through exponentially many different paths.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I've updated my answer. Really shouldn't StackOverflow when tired, I guess